# Distinct() method after merging observables

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android, reactivex

Is there a way to distinct results when doing `Observable.merge(o1, o2)`? 
I'm actually using this snippet of code:

```
public Observable<List<GalleryItem>> getData(int page) {
        return network(page).publish(network -> Observable.merge(network, cache().takeUntil(network))).onErrorResumeNext(cache());
    }
```

The `network()` method is used as a remote data source which saves a list of items to a Room DAO and returns it afterwards.
The `cache()` method is simply retrieving the list from the database.

```
private Observable<List<GalleryItem>> network(int page) {
    return service
            .getItems(page)
            .flatMap(new MapGalleryResponseToPosts(true))
            .doOnNext(galleryItems -> {
                mTopDao.nukeTable();
                mTopDao.saveImages(galleryItems);
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}

private Observable<List<GalleryItem>> cache() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(mTopDao::loadImages).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

It does what it's supposed to do, the cache is displayed before the network call, when the network call executes it's basically duplicating (some) items.

I've tried to use `distinct()` but apparently it doesn't work.

I have also generated the hashCode and equals() because I read that `distinct()` depends on it.

Comment: How did you implement the `equals` and `hashCode`?

Answer (score 1):

Generate `equals` and `hashcode`, for your **GalleryItem** object. `Distinct()` operator will work as expected. Try following code..

```
public Observable<List<GalleryItem>> getData(int page) {
        return Observable.merge(network(page), cache()).distinct()).onErrorResumeNext(cache());
}
```

Simple use case to check `distinct()` operator,

```
    Observable<Integer> values1 = Observable.create(o -> {
        o.onNext(1);
        o.onNext(1);
        o.onNext(2);
        o.onNext(3);
        o.onNext(2);
        o.onComplete();
    });

    Observable<Integer> values2 = Observable.create(o -> {
        o.onNext(1);
        o.onNext(1);
        o.onNext(1);
        o.onNext(2);
        o.onNext(3);
        o.onNext(8);
        o.onNext(9);
        o.onNext(10);
        o.onComplete();
    });

    Observable.merge(values1, values2).distinct().subscribe(
            v -> System.out.println(v),
            e -> System.out.println("Error: " + e),
            () -> System.out.println("Completed")
    );
```

Check the result with `distinct()` and without `distinct()` operator. 
Hope this helps you.